# 0x8007000D error while activating office 2019

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-office, software-activation, microsoft-office-2019

I installed successfully volume version of office 2019.
I was able to activate windows 10 in the same computer
I tried to activatve it manually, here is the error:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16>cscript OSPP.VBS /act
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

---Processing--------------------------
---------------------------------------
Installed product key detected - attempting to activate the following product:
SKU ID: 85dd8b5f-eaa4-4af3-a628-cce9e77c9a03
LICENSE NAME: Office 19, Office19ProPlus2019VL_KMS_Client_AE edition
LICENSE DESCRIPTION: Office 19, VOLUME_KMSCLIENT channel
Last 5 characters of installed product key: 6MWKP
ERROR CODE: 0x8007000D
ERROR DESCRIPTION: Run the following: cscript ospp.vbs /ddescr:0x8007000D
NOTICE: A KB article has been detected for activation failure: 0x8007000D
FOR MORE INFORMATION PLEASE VISIT: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2870357#Error0x8007000D
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
---Exiting-----------------------------
```

in the internet there was a hint to give permission to some registry key, I gave, nothing has changed.
Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Here is the link in your error message>>>>>>https://web.archive.org/web/20131125011328/https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2870357

Answer (score 0):

It seems the link in the error text does not work (well it just gave me a 404 anyway) so I assume you have been searching elsewhere on the web.

This does appear to be an error that has been around a long time, and you should be able to resolve it by following the steps at [this old Windows 7 MS link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/deployment/0x8007000d-activate-machine).

This involves registry key permissions.

You already mentioned registry changes but you did not give the specifics so this may be different, or you may need to check you are fully following the steps.